# Android: Repeat Function until Button is pressed

Tags: android, function, kotlin, repeat

So I want the function "start()" to be called every second until I press a Button.

The function reads a JSON File and notifies a Plotter to Print a Line graph with the help of `GraphView` Library.

I tried this but the App keeps Crashing:

```
private val timer = Timer("schedule", true)
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(1000,1000)
{
   start()
}
```

Json Parser: Connecting to URL, pull json and extract Data from it.

```
object JsonParser {

var blueConeArray = arrayListOf<Cone>()
var yellowConeArray = arrayListOf<Cone>()

//Parse Json File extract Data and store them in DataWarehouse
fun parse(url: String) {

    getRequest(url, success = { response ->

        //create Parser
        val parser = Parser()
        val stringBuilder = StringBuilder(response)

        //Read Json File + get Data
        val jsonObject : JsonObject = parser.parse(stringBuilder) as JsonObject

        //Get Cones from JsonObject
        val blueCoordinates : JsonArray<JsonObject>? = jsonObject.array("BlueCoordinates")
        val yellowCoordinates : JsonArray<JsonObject>? = jsonObject.array("YellowCoordinates")

        //Store Blue Cones
        for(coordinate in blueCoordinates!!)
        {
            var x_blue = coordinate.double("x")
            var y_blue = coordinate.double("y")

            var blueCone =  BlueCone(x_blue!!, y_blue!!)
            blueConeArray.add(blueCone)
        }

        //Store Yellow Cones
        for(coordinate in yellowCoordinates!!)
        {
            var x_yellow = coordinate.double("x")
            var y_yellow = coordinate.double("y")
            var yellowCone = YellowCone(x_yellow!!, y_yellow!!)
            yellowConeArray.add(yellowCone)
        }

        //Store everything in Data Warehouse
       DataWarehouse.setValues(newEngineTemp = jsonObject.string("engineTemp"),
                                newSpeed = jsonObject.string("speed"),
                                newBlueCones = blueConeArray,
                                newYellowCones = yellowConeArray)
        blueConeArray.clear()
        yellowConeArray.clear()

    }, failure = { error ->
        println(error)
    })
}

//connect to URL pull Json File
private fun getRequest(url: String, success: (String) -> Unit, failure: (FuelError) -> Unit) {

    Fuel.get(url).responseString { request, response, result ->

        val (data, error) = result
        if (error != null) {
            Log.v("Error", error.toString())
            failure(error)
        } else {
            val onSuccess = data ?: return@responseString
            success(onSuccess)
        }
    }
}
```

}

DataWarehouse: Stores Data from Json Parser and notifies Observers

```
object DataWarehouse : Subject {

//List of Observers
private val MAXOBSERVER = 100
private var amountOfObservers = 0
private var observerList = arrayListOf<Observer>()

//Data from car
private var engineTemp: String? = ""
private var speed: String? = ""
private lateinit var blueCones : ArrayList<Cone>
private lateinit var yellowCones : ArrayList<Cone>

//register Observers + save them in Array
override fun registerObserver(DataObserver: Observer) {

    if (amountOfObservers < MAXOBSERVER) {
        observerList.add(DataObserver)
        amountOfObservers++
    }
}

//notify Observer from Array, that needs the new Value
override fun notifyObservers() {
    for (observer in observerList) {
        observer.update()
    }
}

//set values from parsed Jason File
fun setValues(newEngineTemp: String?, newSpeed: String? ,newBlueCones: ArrayList<Cone>, newYellowCones: ArrayList<Cone>) {

    //set new Values
    engineTemp = newEngineTemp
    speed = newSpeed
    blueCones = newBlueCones
    yellowCones = newYellowCones

    //notify all Observers
    notifyObservers()
}

//Return values to Observers
fun getEngineTemp(): String? {
    return engineTemp
}

fun getSpeed(): String? {
    return speed
}

fun getBlueCones(): ArrayList<Cone> {

    return blueCones
}

fun getYellowCones(): ArrayList<Cone> {

    return yellowCones
}
```

}

GraphView Plotter: first create DataPoints at (0/0) so "resetData()" works.

```
class Plotter(graphView: GraphView) : Observer {

private var graphView = graphView

private lateinit var sortedBlueCones: MutableList<Cone>
private lateinit var sortedYellowCones: MutableList<Cone>

private var blueConeArrayList = ArrayList<DataPoint>()
private var yellowConeArrayList = ArrayList<DataPoint>()

private var blueLines = LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>()
private var yellowLines = LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>()

private var blueIterator = 0
private var yellowIterator = 0

private var firstDraw = true

init {

    //First Values so resetData works
    yellowLines.appendData((DataPoint(0.toDouble(), 0.toDouble())), true, 1000)
    blueLines.appendData((DataPoint(0.toDouble(), 0.toDouble())), true, 1000)

    register()
}

//Register at Data Warehouse
override fun register() {
    DataWarehouse.registerObserver(this)
}

//Get new Cones from Data Warehouse and sort them by X Values
override fun update() {

    sortedBlueCones = DataWarehouse.getBlueCones().sortedWith(compareBy({ it.xCoordinate })) as MutableList<Cone>
    sortedYellowCones = DataWarehouse.getYellowCones().sortedWith(compareBy({ it.xCoordinate })) as MutableList<Cone>

    draw()
}

//Draw Line Graph and Point Graph
private fun draw() {

        //Blue Cones
        for (i in sortedBlueCones) {

            var x: Double = sortedBlueCones.get(blueIterator).xCoordinate
            var y: Double = sortedBlueCones.get(blueIterator).yCoordinate

            var dataPoint = DataPoint(x, y)
            blueConeArrayList.add(dataPoint)
            val blueConeArray = arrayOfNulls<DataPoint>(blueConeArrayList.size)
            blueConeArrayList.toArray(blueConeArray)

            blueLines.resetData(blueConeArray)

            blueIterator++
        }


        //Yellow Cones
        for (i in sortedYellowCones) {
            var x: Double = sortedYellowCones.get(yellowIterator).xCoordinate
            var y: Double = sortedYellowCones.get(yellowIterator).yCoordinate

            var dataPoint = DataPoint(x, y)
            yellowConeArrayList.add(dataPoint)
            val yellowConeArray = arrayOfNulls<DataPoint>(yellowConeArrayList.size)
            yellowConeArrayList.toArray(yellowConeArray)

            yellowLines.resetData(yellowConeArray)

            yellowIterator++
        }

    //Set Values of Lines
    blueLines.setColor(Color.BLUE)
    blueLines.setDrawDataPoints(true)
    blueLines.setDataPointsRadius(10.toFloat())

    yellowLines.setColor(Color.YELLOW)
    yellowLines.setDrawDataPoints(true)
    yellowLines.setDataPointsRadius(10.toFloat())

    //Draw
    graphView.addSeries(blueLines)
    graphView.addSeries(yellowLines)

    blueIterator = 0
    yellowIterator = 0
}
```

}

Error Stack: It looks like a Problem of graphView, but when I trigger the function manually with a Button it just works fine. Whenever i wrap "start()" or "readJson()" in a timer the App crashes.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.tobias.infinity_racing_driverless, PID: 16341
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The order of the values is not correct. X-Values have to be ordered ASC. First the lowest x value and at least the highest x value.
    at com.jjoe64.graphview.series.BaseSeries.checkValueOrder(BaseSeries.java:532)
    at com.jjoe64.graphview.series.BaseSeries.resetData(BaseSeries.java:412)
    at com.example.tobias.infinity_racing_driverless.Plotter.draw(Plotter.kt:69)
    at com.example.tobias.infinity_racing_driverless.Plotter.update(Plotter.kt:52)
    at com.example.tobias.infinity_racing_driverless.DataWarehouse.notifyObservers(DataWarehouse.kt:32)
    at com.example.tobias.infinity_racing_driverless.DataWarehouse.setValues(DataWarehouse.kt:46)
    at com.example.tobias.infinity_racing_driverless.JsonParser$parse$1.invoke(JsonParser.kt:55)
    at com.example.tobias.infinity_racing_driverless.JsonParser$parse$1.invoke(JsonParser.kt:14)
    at com.example.tobias.infinity_racing_driverless.JsonParser$getRequest$1.invoke(JsonParser.kt:78)
    at com.example.tobias.infinity_racing_driverless.JsonParser$getRequest$1.invoke(JsonParser.kt:14)
    at com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.DeserializableKt$response$1.invoke(Deserializable.kt:105)
    at com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.DeserializableKt$response$1.invoke(Unknown Source:4)
    at com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.DeserializableKt$response$asyncRequest$1$1.invoke(Deserializable.kt:192)
    at com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.DeserializableKt$response$asyncRequest$1$1.invoke(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.RequestExecutionOptionsKt$sam$java_lang_Runnable$0.run(Unknown Source:2)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: What's the crash you're getting? Show the stack trace

Comment: Show your full code and stacktrace where crash occurs as well.

Comment: Hi, I edited the Post with almost the full Code and stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

1) Timer schedules the task on worker thread. I guess the error happens because *start()* function is updating the GraphView(UI) on worker thread. so try wrapping the start function inside the UI/Main handler like below.

```
private val timer = Timer("schedule", true)
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(1000,1000)
{
  Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
            start()
        }
}
```

2) But again if it takes time to read json file, better to just wrap the Grapview update code inside Handler instead of whole start() function. Hence code inside your *start()* function has to be like below

```
fun start()
{
    // your code to read the json file

    // wrap the notify grapview plotter inside Handler
    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
        // code to notify Grapview plotter 
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it looks like a Problem with graphView and a weird way it behaves when called multiple times. I will try your solution and give you feedback if it worked.

I edited the Post maybe you can see what the Problem is (it's my first time working with graphView)